# com.bea.wli.monitoring.MonitoringException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server 'null' not found

Tags: java, weblogic

I have java code that uses Java Management Extensions (JMX) monitoring API to get service statistics data from oracle weblogic console.
I have a production server and a testing server.
this java code works fine and gets service statistics data from weblogic console of testing server. when i run this code for production server it shows the below error :

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy0.getProxyServiceStatistics(Unknown Source)
    at reports.All_ServiceStatisticsReport.getProxyServiceDetails(All_ServiceStatisticsReport.java:235)
    at reports.All_ServiceStatisticsReport.<init>(All_ServiceStatisticsReport.java:189)
    at reports.All_ServiceStatisticsReport.main(All_ServiceStatisticsReport.java:567)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at reports.All_ServiceStatisticsReport$ServiceDomainMBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(All_ServiceStatisticsReport.java:145)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.bea.wli.monitoring.MonitoringException: [OSB-473057]Failed to get statistics for services due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server 'null' not found
    at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server 'null' not found
    ... 1 more
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

the line where the error occurs is :

```
proxyServiceResourceStatisticMap = serviceDomainMbean.getProxyServiceStatistics(filteredProxyServiceRefs,resourceType.value(),null);
```

I am passing all the right arguments according to the oracle docs.

```
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/java-api/com/bea/wli/monitoring/ServiceDomainMBean.html
```

then why i am getting this error.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server 'null' not found". The last argument to `getProxyServiceStatistics`, the server name, is specified as `null`.

Comment: yes,  the method ``java.util.HashMap<Ref,ServiceResourceStatistic> getProxyServiceStatistics(Ref[] serviceRefs,int resourceTypes,java.lang.String serverName)throws DomainMonitoringDisabledException,MonitoringException,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException``  takes these arguments. where if the last argument is null then it returns cluster level statistics.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/java-api/com/bea/wli/monitoring/ServiceDomainMBean.html

Comment: when i change the server ip,port, username and password from production server to testing server on the same code , it works fine.